# How to Remove chatter header?

Tags: visualforce, community, visualforce-component, chatter

[image: Chatter Image]

How can i remove chatter header (in black). This is a iframe.

Comment: Use some jquery hack with DOM if this is a deal breaker .You should be able to trace the DOM

Answer (score 0):

will this help

apex:page showHeader="false"

chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!$User.Id}"

apex:page
Please put the proper syntax in apex tags.I m facing some problems to post with tags.

Hit Kudos if this provides you with useful information and if this is what you where looking for then please mark it as a solution for other benefits